# Flow based Routing Linux

Tags: linux, routes

How to add a route for a subnet that is reachable via two different gateways. The Problem is I want both of routes to be used for a FLOW. For example FLOW one uses first gateway and FLOW two uses second gateway. I have heard this can be achieved using Equal Cost Multi-Path. But that round-robins per packet. How to do that for Flows in a Linux Based System

Answer (score 0):

Since linux kernel 4.17 there are two options to set a mulitpath routing hashing algorithm. The default is Layer 3 hashing ie srcip+dstip and what usually is being used on most routing devices is L4\5 hashing. The hashing defines what a "flow" might be defined by the linux fib.
You can define the hashing algorithm used by defining sysctl values on the OS.

For example the 4 or 5 tuple(not sure) flow hashing is 1 so the next would define it for both IPv4 and IPv6

```
sysctl net.ipv4.fib_multipath_hash_policy=1
sysctl net.ipv6.fib_multipath_hash_policy=1
```

And from the linux kernel docs:

```
fib_multipath_hash_policy - INTEGER
Controls which hash policy to use for multipath routes. Only valid for kernels built with CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_MULTIPATH enabled.

Default: 0 (Layer 3)

Possible values:

0 - Layer 3

1 - Layer 4

2 - Layer 3 or inner Layer 3 if present

3 - Custom multipath hash. Fields used for multipath hash calculation are determined by fib_multipath_hash_fields sysctl
```